# Something is making my program crash, I know which chunk of code it is but I don't know why

Tags: c++, c++11, crash, interpreter

My program without bit that crashes that works fine just as I want it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<int,std::string> strlist;

strlist get_program(std::string RELPATH)
{
    std::ifstream file(RELPATH);
    strlist out;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::getline(file,out[i+1]);
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    strlist program=get_program("program.txt");
    strlist tokenlist=get_tokens(program[1],' '); //in the "version of the program that doesn't crash",
//this line is removed due to the functions it is directly and indirectly referring to being removed
    std::string in,out;
    std::cout<<"[Cyan 0.1]\n";
    std::cin>>in;
    for(int i=1;i<=program.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout<<program[i]<<"\n";
    }
    std::cin>>in;
    return 0;
}
```

The part whose existence in the program somehow causes the crash (it is put right before the main function):

```
bool checkforchars(std::string chars,char c) //Returns true if one of char's in given string is identical to given char c
{
for(int i=0; i<chars.length();i++)
    {
        if(chars[i]==c) {return true;}
    }
return false;
}

strlist get_tokens(std::string in,char tokenCut)
{ //Returns an ordered (by occurence) list of strings with each string containing a single token. The separation of tokens is decided by the single character specified by tokenCut
    strlist tokens;
    int token_amnt=1;
    for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++)
    {
    if(in[i]==tokenCut)
        {
            token_amnt++;
        }
    else
        {
            tokens[token_amnt]=tokens[token_amnt]+in[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I am making an interpreter (I'm calling it "Cyan") and the program without the "crashy" bit works fine and prints the lines of program.txt once I've given it some input (first input doesn't actually do/affect anything other than delay the next bit until the user inputs). If I add the "crashy" bit along with the line "strlist tokenlist=get_tokens(program[1],' ');" then it crashes, but there's two weird things:

- It only crashes the moment "return 0;" is executed (I know this because the last input is so that I can get the program to close when I like, and when I give it that last input it crashes)
- It does the same thing even if I remove the "strlist tokenlist=get_tokens(program[1],' ');" line, which implies that the existence of the "crashy functions" in the program is the cause of it crashing when the program ends

If it crashed the moment that line involving the "crashy functions" executed then it would've made a lot more sense, although I'd still be equally clueless about what is making it crash. I am using MinGW for Windows 7 (32-bit) and compiling using

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o program.exe
```

if that helps in any way.

Comment: Is your question, "How do you debug a C++ program?" If not, what is it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My question is "what is making my program crash?". The program compiles fine without any errors and it runs fine too, UNTIL, it reaches the "return 0;" bit which crashes it. However, if I include that line bit that refers to (indirectly) the crashy bit, then it crashes there instead.

Comment: I don't see a "insert()" anywhere - that can't be good :(.  http://thispointer.com/stdmap-tutorial-part-1-usage-detail-with-examples/

Comment: `return 0` crashing is a real good indicator you have overwritten something on the stack and destroyed the return address.

Comment: You are missing `return tokens;` at the end of `get_tokens()`

Comment: @NathanOliver Well that's fixed it crashing when I haven't called the function, and it's also fixed it crashing when I have called the function, so thanks! I haven't tried outputting the output of the function yet though... I'll try it now

Comment: It's fixed that too, and the function is working properly :D Thanks for the help. The things crashing my programs usually turn out to be really dumb things lol

Comment: @godofllamas -- Just to make you aware: `for(int i=1;i<=program.size();i++)   std::cout<<program[i]<<"\n";` The `program` is a `std::map`, not an array.   If you expect that loop to work the same as if `program` is an array, you're mistaken.  You may wind up erroneously inserting empty elements in the map with that loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It seems to work, and I can access different members of the std::map with "program[2]="line 2"", can't I?

Comment: @godofllamas Your code will not work as you intended if you populated your map using non-consecutive keys, starting from key 1.  For example, if you got to that loop, and your map has keys 1, 3, 5, 9, 10, your printing loop would stick in (by mistake) empty keys 2, and 4.  You can thank using `operator [ ]` for that behavior.  Instead, use iterators to loop through your map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I prefer using my own iterator and just making sure I number them 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. because I have no idea how the iterator thingie works and it looks too finicky to get to work, plus it looks nicer (IMO)

Comment: @godofllamas Doesn't really address the issue I raised.  You are inserting empty entries in your map if you use `i`, start the loop at `1`, and your map before the loop consists of non-consecutive keys.  Don't believe me?  Just try it. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5936a059a62fd56

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Isn't the solution to that to just make sure you aren't skipping numbers and you always "add stuff" at the next largest number that hasn't "been taken" (don't know what a proper term would be) and then iterate through them from 1 to the amount that has "been taken"? I don't see why that wouldn't work, and that's what I'm doing with this "self-made iterator method".

Comment: @godofllamas You're not getting the point I'm making with the code I showed you.  Assume for one second that the map in that code was not initialized that way, and instead, was created by your program in your `get_tokens` loop.  Now you send that map to the output routine you wrote.  You now have a bug because you're erroneously creating empty entries during the output.  The bottom line is to not use `map::operator[ ]` just willy-nilly as you're doing now.  It has side-effects, which the code I showed you illustrates.  The misuse of `map::operator[ ]` is the cause of many a bug.